# Why do my Sharepoint2010 breadcrumbs not level down on pages with embeddeded links?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, breadcrumbs

I have a Sharepoint site that currently inherits everything from the v4.master page.

This site in an internal wiki page for company documentation.  Each page within the wiki can have 1 or more pages linked inside of it.  For instance:

```
Wiki Main  
  └Finance  
      └AP Reports  
      └AR Reports   
   └Human Resources  
      └Payroll  
      └Benefits
```

We have been embedding new pages using this code `[[FinancePage|Finance Documentation Page]]` on each 'parent' page.

The issue I'm having is that the breadcrumbs do not seem to follow the leveling when users click links.

The breadcrumbs will show the following: `Wiki Main > Finance`

Then when the click AP Reports it will show this: `Wiki Main > AP Reports`

What I'd like it to show is this: `Wiki main > Finance > AP Reports`

I'll be the first to admit I have zero experience with Sharepoint and when googling there are quite a few hits that seem to go into making my own DLL or replacing .sitemap*.xml file but Im not sure if that is the correct solution to what Im trying to do.

Is there a way to get the breadcrumb leveling to work correctly via a Site Setting?